# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-win32-3550

Tags: android, sdk

after installing android sdk and running sdk manager, i encounter the problem of flash back. then i added some echo statements in android.bat and execute it. the result is as follows:

also i copy swt-awt-win32-3550.dll etc to D:\android-sdk\sdk\tools\,  and no work

the result:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-win32-3550 or
swt-win32 in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file

java_exe 'C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_4\bin\java.exe'
remote_debug ''
toolsdir 'D:\android-sdk\sdk\tools'
workdir 'D:\android-sdk\sdk\tools'
jar_path 'lib\sdkmanager.jar;lib\swtmenubar.jar'
swt_path 'lib\x86_64'

Answer (score 1):

i myself anwser my own question and it may be helpful for someone. finally i could run SDK manager at the way:

D:\android-sdk\sdk>java -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir=D:\android-sdk\sdk\tools -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.workdir=D:\android-sdk\sdk\tools -classpath lib\sdkmanager.jar;lib\swtmenubar.jar;lib\x86_64\swt.jar com.android.sdkmanager.Main